SDL2 not throwing window close event
For personal use, I'm coding an additional layer on SDL2, which includes an event manager. It correctly detects every type of event, except SDL_WINDOWEVENT_CLOSE. After trying to debug my code, I realized that SDL2 actually never fires that event on my device... So there's no problem when I have only 1 window (because SDL_QUIT is thrown instead), but when I have several windows I just can't detect when a window closing is requested, and I have to ctrl+C my program from the shell to have SDL_QUIT fired manually.
Here is a minimal working example :
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

int main(void){
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    
    SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow("A title", 0, 0, 720, 480, 0);
    SDL_Window *window2 = SDL_CreateWindow("Another title", 0, 500, 720, 480, 0);

    SDL_Event event;
    _Bool running = 1;
    while (running){
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)){
            if (event.type == SDL_WINDOWEVENT_CLOSE){
                printf("Close event !\n");
                running = 0;
            }
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT){
                printf("Quit event !\n");
                running = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window2);

    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}

On my device nothing happens when I try to close a window (I am under Ubuntu 24.04 LTS, if this may help)
Am I missing something ?

The event.type will not be SDL_WINDOWEVENT_CLOSE but SDL_WINDOWEVENT. That event type then has a lot of events defined for it, like SDL_WINDOWEVENT_CLOSE.
Your loop could therefore look like this instead:
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("A title", 0, 0, 720, 480, 0);
    SDL_Window* window2 = SDL_CreateWindow("Another title", 0, 500, 720, 480, 0);

    SDL_Event event;
    _Bool running = 1;
    while(running) {
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            switch(event.type) {
                case SDL_QUIT: {
                    puts("SDL_QUIT");
                    running = 0;
                    break;
                }
                case SDL_WINDOWEVENT: {
                    SDL_WindowEvent* we = (SDL_WindowEvent*)&event;
                    switch(we->event) {
                        case SDL_WINDOWEVENT_CLOSE: {
                            puts("SDL_WINDOWEVENT_CLOSE");
                            running = 0;
                            break;
                         }
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window2);

    SDL_Quit();
}


SDL_Event::type holds a SDL_EventType value, not a SDL_WindowEventID.
Check event.type against SDL_WINDOWEVENT and event.window.event against SDL_WINDOWEVENT_CLOSE.
